# 3D matrix truth table

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, 3d

I'm having difficulty conceptualizing a 3 dimensional matrix, which I need for a truth table of sorts. I am trying to go through a 3D matrix, and compare each element to all other elements adjacent to it (but not on diagonals). I have a function (truth_table) which is supposed to take a set of 3D coordinates and return a matrix which tells me which surrounding coordinates are safe to call upon without fear of an INDEX_OUT_OF_BOUNDS exception. I am new to N-dimensional matrices and am having trouble making this truth table, which was easy enough in 2D.

```
import numpy as np
array_rows=10
array_cols=10
array_height=10
laser_power=2e-3

T_MATRIX=np.full((array_rows,array_cols,array_height),0.0)
H_MATRIX=np.full((array_rows,array_cols,array_height),0.0)
H_MATRIX[5,5,5]=laser_power
constants=0.5

def truth_table(row,col,height):
    skeleton=np.array([
    [[False,False,False],[False,height<array_height-1,False],[False,False,False]],[[False,row>0,False],[col>0,False,col<array_cols-1],[False,row<array_rows-1,False]],[[False,False,False],[False,height>0,False],[False,False,False]]])

def update_T():
    global T_MATRIX
    for row in range(array_rows):
        for col in range(array_cols):
            for height in range(array_height):
                T_MATRIX[row][col][height]+=H_MATRIX[row][col][height]*constants

def reset_H():
    global H_MATRIX
    for row in range(array_rows):
        for col in range(array_cols):
            for height in range(array_height):
                H_MATRIX[row][col][height]=0.0
    H_MATRIX[5,5,5]=laser_power

def update_H():
    global H_MATRIX
    for row in range(array_rows):
        for col in range(array_cols):
            for height in range(array_height):
                my_table=truth_table(row,col,height)
                count=np.sum(my_table)
                T_DIFF=0.0
                AVG_T=0.0
                for r in range(3):
                    for c in range(3):
                        for h in range(3):
                            if(my_table[r][c][h]):
                                T_DIFF+=T_MATRIX[row][col][height]-T_MATRIX[row+(r-1)][col+(c-1)][height+(h-1)]
                if(count>0):
                    AVG_T=T_DIFF/count
                H_MATRIX[row][col][height]+=T_DIFF*constants


def update_stuff():
    ##UPDATE THE TEMP
    update_T()
    reset_H()
    update_H()


update_stuff()
print T_MATRIX[5][5][5]
#print constants
```

Comment: Just in case: can you describe exactly what you plan to do with such a matrix?  It sounds like you have an [x-y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  It you are using this function to get indices to then plug into a different function, there may be *much* better ways to proceed than the solution to your current question (e.g. convolution).

Answer (score 0):

Because this question is likely going to be abandoned or closed, here is something that might help your thinking about this problem.  It looks like you are doing things where you are interested in calculating differences/averages between a cell's values and the value's of its nearest neighbors.

On a 3D lattice, a cell's nearest neighbors are located at the following positions (centered on the cell of interest):

```
[[[0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0],
  [0, 0, 0]],
 [[0, 1, 0],
  [1, 0, 1],
  [0, 1, 0]],
 [[0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0],
  [0, 0, 0]]]
```

which can be constructed with numpy using

```
f = np.zeros((3,3,3))
f[[0,1,1,1,1,2],[1,0,1,1,2,1],[1,1,0,2,1,1]] = 1
```

The [convolution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve.html) of this nearest-neighbor filter (or kernel) with any 3D array A1 of shape (N1,N2,N3) will give you a new array A2 of shape (N1,N2,N3) where each value in A2 is the sum of the neighbors' values in A1.  For example:

```
>>> A1 = np.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3)
>>> A1
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26]]])

>>> A2 = scipy.ndimage.convolve(A1, f)
>>> A2
array([[[ 13,  18,  23],
        [ 28,  33,  38],
        [ 43,  48,  53]],

       [[ 58,  63,  68],
        [ 73,  78,  83],
        [ 88,  93,  98]],

       [[103, 108, 113],
        [118, 123, 128],
        [133, 138, 143]]])
```

The first entry of A2 is 13 = 1 + 3 + 9.  The middle entry of A2 is 78 = 4 + 10 + 12 + 14 + 16 + 22.

You can use these convolutions to easily get some of the quantities you are looking for.  It looks like `H_MATRIX` could be constructed simply by

```
H_MATRIX = constants * (T_MATRIX - convolve(T_MAXTRIX, f))
```

using the `f` defined above.  Alternatively, you could define a different `f` that has a 1 in the center and -1 at the other 6 positions which might give you just `H_MATRIX = constants * convolve(T_MATRIX, f)`.